# Removing OSGeo4w packages without removing program fully

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w

I want to remove OSGeo4w to the base program without removing the program entirely. I am not using QGIS right now, but will in the future. I want to just remove some of the extra packages (and open some space up on my PC), but everytime I run the uninstall it adds to the storage size instead of removing. Before running the uninstall it was a total of 5.2GB.

[image: storage on computer]
[image: tried running uninstall using OSGeo4w.exe]

Comment: Do you mean that uninstalling QGIS added 1.5 GB into your OSGeo4W directory? That feels odd.

Comment: That's odd. Are you using the online installation option?

Comment: QGIS is installed but, was trying to remove the extra OSGeo4W packages. When going through the removal process in OSGeo4W, it used up more of my storage instead of uninstalling. I was using the OSGeo4W GUI to uninstall it.